# error: function ammarkpos is not defined for index document_bt_id_sys_period_app_period_excl

Tags: postgresql

I query DB. All is OK, but when I add `FULL JOIN` I get the error [debug output is here: pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pkWLCY86):

```sql
SELECT
    *
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM "document" WHERE TRUE OR agreement_id = 1109 ) d
  -- This line cause problem:
  FULL JOIN (select * from ( VALUES ( 'StopAgreement' ) ) AS t( doctype) ) stop ON true
  WHERE d.id IS NULL  OR   d.document_type IN ( 'NewAgreement', 'ChangeAgreement', 'StopAgreement' )
;
ERROR:  function ammarkpos is not defined for index document_bt_id_sys_period_app_period_excl
```

The definition of mentioned index is:

```
"document_bt_id_sys_period_app_period_excl" EXCLUDE USING gist (id WITH =, sys_period WITH &&, app_period WITH &&)
```

What is wrong with my `FULL JOIN`? How can I resolve the error?

```sql
select * from version();
 PostgreSQL 13.0 (Debian 13.0-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian
 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

**UPDATE**
This problem is reproduced on `PostgreSQL v11.5` also.

```sql
tucha=> \dS+ document;
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |   Default    | Storage  | Description 
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+-------------
 id            | integer                  |           |          |              | plain    | 
 owner_id      | integer                  |           |          |              | plain    | 
 document_type | character varying(32)    |           |          |              | extended | 
 docn          | character varying(32)    |           |          |              | extended | 
 docdate       | date                     |           |          |              | plain    | 
 agreement_id  | integer                  |           |          |              | plain    | 
 info          | json                     |           |          | '{}'::json   | extended | 
 prow_date     | timestamp with time zone |           |          |              | plain    | 
 app_period    | tstzrange                |           |          | app_period() | extended | 
View definition:
 SELECT document_bt.id,
    document_bt.owner_id,
    document_bt.document_type,
    document_bt.docn,
    document_bt.docdate,
    document_bt.agreement_id,
    document_bt.info,
    document_bt.prow_date,
    document_bt.app_period
   FROM document_bt
  WHERE document_bt.sys_period @> sys_time() AND (biconf('app_period'::text) IS NULL OR document_bt.app_period && biconf('app_period'::text)::tstzrange);
Triggers:
    document_bt_delete INSTEAD OF DELETE ON document FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE document_bt_delete()
    document_bt_insert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON document FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE document_bt_insert()
    document_bt_update INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON document FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE document_bt_update()

tucha=> \d document_bt
                                                                            Table "public.document_bt"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                                 Default                                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id            | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('document_id_seq'::regclass)                                    | plain    |              | 
 owner_id      | integer                  |           |          |                                                                         | plain    |              | 
 document_type | character varying(32)    |           | not null |                                                                         | extended |              | 
 docn          | character varying(32)    |           | not null |                                                                         | extended |              | 
 docdate       | date                     |           | not null | now()                                                                   | plain    |              | 
 agreement_id  | integer                  |           |          |                                                                         | plain    |              | 
 info          | json                     |           | not null | '{}'::json                                                              | extended |              | 
 sid           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('document_bt_sid_seq'::regclass)                                | plain    |              | 
 app_period    | tstzrange                |           | not null | app_period()                                                            | extended |              | 
 sys_period    | tstzrange                |           | not null | tstzrange(sys_time(), 'infinity'::timestamp with time zone, '[)'::text) | extended |              | 
 prow_date     | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                                                         | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "document_bt_id_sys_period_app_period_excl" EXCLUDE USING gist (id WITH =, sys_period WITH &&, app_period WITH &&)
Check constraints:
    "document_bt_sys_period_check" CHECK (NOT isempty(sys_period))
```

When I empty the table. Query works.
When I add one line into the table, query works.
When I dump/restore database: query does not work

**UPDATE**
Plan for CTE which works:

```sql
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Merge Full Join  (cost=3177.93..3177.98 rows=1 width=284) (actual time=4.994..16.219 rows=53 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                          |
  CTE x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
    ->  Index Scan using document_bt_id_sys_period_app_period_excl on document_bt  (cost=0.53..3177.93 rows=1 width=75) (actual time=4.969..16.071 rows=53 loops=1)                                                                                            |
          Index Cond: (sys_period @> sys_time())                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
          Filter: (((id IS NULL) OR ((document_type)::text = ANY ('{NewAgreement,ChangeAgreement,StopAgreement}'::text[]))) AND ((NULLIF(current_setting('my.app_period'::text, true), ''::text) IS NULL) OR (app_period && (NULLIF(current_setting('my.app_per|
          Rows Removed by Filter: 9251                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
  ->  CTE Scan on x  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=252) (actual time=4.977..16.149 rows=53 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                            |
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.009..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                 |
        ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                |
Planning Time: 0.536 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
Execution Time: 16.303 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
```

Plan when query does not work:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT
    *
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM "document" ) d
  FULL JOIN (select * from ( VALUES ( 'StopAgreement' ) ) AS t( doctype) ) stop ON true
  WHERE d.id IS NULL  OR   d.document_type IN ( 'NewAgreement', 'ChangeAgreement', 'StopAgreement' );
ERROR:  function ammarkpos is not defined for index document_bt_id_sys_period_app_period_excl
```

**UPDATE**
Without analyse

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    *
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM "document" ) d
  FULL JOIN (select * from ( VALUES ( 'StopAgreement' ) ) AS t( doctype) ) stop ON true
  WHERE d.id IS NULL  OR   d.document_type IN ( 'NewAgreement', 'ChangeAgreement', 'StopAgreement' );
QUERY PLAN                                                                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Full Join  (cost=0.53..3144.17 rows=1 width=107)
   Filter: ((document_bt.id IS NULL) OR ((document_bt.document_type)::text = ANY ('{NewAgreement,ChangeAgreement,StopAgreement}'::text[])))
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32)
   ->  Index Scan using document_bt_id_sys_period_app_period_excl on document_bt  (cost=0.53..3142.18 rows=143 width=75)
         Index Cond: (sys_period @> sys_time())
         Filter: ((NULLIF(current_setting('my.app_period'::text, true), ''::text) IS NULL) OR (app_period && (NULLIF(current_setting('my.app_period'::text, true), ''::text))::tstzrange))
(6 rows)


EXPLAIN WITH x AS (SELECT
    *
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM "document" WHERE TRUE OR agreement_id = 1109 ) d
  WHERE d.id IS NULL  OR   d.document_type IN ( 'NewAgreement', 'ChangeAgreement', 'StopAgreement' )
)

SELECT * FROM x
 FULL JOIN (select * from ( VALUES ( 'StopAgreement' ) ) AS t( doctype) ) stop ON true

;
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Merge Full Join  (cost=3177.93..3177.98 rows=1 width=284)                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
  CTE x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
    ->  Index Scan using document_bt_id_sys_period_app_period_excl on document_bt  (cost=0.53..3177.93 rows=1 width=75)                                                                                                                                        |
          Index Cond: (sys_period @> sys_time())                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
          Filter: (((id IS NULL) OR ((document_type)::text = ANY ('{NewAgreement,ChangeAgreement,StopAgreement}'::text[]))) AND ((NULLIF(current_setting('my.app_period'::text, true), ''::text) IS NULL) OR (app_period && (NULLIF(current_setting('my.app_per|
  ->  CTE Scan on x  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=252)                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
        ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32)                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
```

Comment: What is the definition of the mentioned index?

Comment: @jjanes: Added definition for the index

Comment: The index is missing a method which is needed to do the FULL JOIN, but in that case it 
should not have chosen that index to work with in the first place.  This certainly looks like a bug, but I can't reproduce it.  Can you give us the CREATE statement for the table?  If you make an empty table with the same definition, do you get an error for it?  Have you done the same thing in prior versions of PostgreSQL (and did they work?)?

Comment: @jjanes: I have added requested info

Answer (score 0):

To resolve error I can rewrite query a bit:

```sql
WITH x AS (SELECT
    *
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM "document" WHERE TRUE OR agreement_id = 1109 ) d
  WHERE d.id IS NULL  OR   d.document_type IN ( 'NewAgreement', 'ChangeAgreement', 'StopAgreement' )
)

SELECT * FROM x
-- This FULL JOIN do noting =(
FULL JOIN (select * from ( VALUES ( 'StopAgreement' ) ) AS t( doctype) ) stop ON true
```

**UPDATE**

This was edge case. See [hacker maillist](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/87o8jn50be.fsf@news-spur.riddles.org.uk). There will be fix in next version =)

Thank you `RhodiumToad` from irc channel to investigate into this.